# Closed question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

Five people voted to close https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174730/best-way-to-build-api, before anyone said why they thought it should be closed. I tried to improve the text. It seems like a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd probably close it for the "Not constructive" reason:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

Generally any question that's "what's the best..." is going to solicit opinion and debate, and aren't what SO is for.

Comment: You can't always judge a question by its title. When you read it this one turns out to be more of an an "How to" question.

Answer (score 8):

The question is rather generic, without any details that allows to give a more specific answer.

> I want to build an API in my project that will allow developers to send parameters to my application.

That is a generic description for a web service. If the question would not have said, "send parameters" I could have thought of a generic API.

> My application will make some operations and return a class back.

There isn't a description of the operations made, or the type of class being returned. I can just expect a very generic answer.

> Is a web service the best way?

The answer depends from the operations being done. I would not create a web service for just calculating the sum of two numbers, but a web service could be created to make a complex calculation.

> I am working with Visual Studio 2010 and I didn't see an option to add a web service project…
>
> What do you suggest?

The fact the question is too generic is evident from the answer, which contains a link to a page titled, "What Is Windows Communication Foundation."
Without any detail about the specific API, or the kind of operation being executed, it is difficult to say if a web service is appropriate. Without any detail, any user would suppose a specific case, and answer for that specific case; if the users don't suppose a specific case, then the answer can just be as generic as possible. In the first case, what the OP would get is a set of answers that are equally valid, which could help the user only if who answers guesses the specific case the OP is referring. In this case, the question is not even useful to future readers, as they could not have clear in which case the accepted answer (if it is not the most generic one) is applicable.

Comment: I want a metal box that can carry me from one point to another over long distances.  What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Should not you buy an airplane ticket? `:-)`

Comment: Oh shnitz, I never considered that!

Comment: An airplane ticket? I don't think any airline will give me a flight from my cubicle to the men's room....

Comment: @JackManey If the distance between them can be considered long distance, why not? You can always try, and see what they reply. `;)`

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar fix-ups definitely helped, but I'm still unclear if he is looking for advice on good API design principles or looking for advice on which buttons to click to get his IDE to emit a pile of boilerplate code for him to fill in with his API details.

[Jon Skeet's Writing the Perfect Question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) has a lot of advice of what makes for a *good* question. The current state of the question doesn't fit my idea of a *good* question and no amount of copy-editing can bring it there -- only the original questioner can fill in the missing details to his question.